# Convert R dataframe from long to wide format, but with unequal group sizes, for use with qcc

Tags: r, reshape, qcc

I would like to convert a dataframe from long format to a wide format, but with unequal group sizes.

The eventual use will be in 'qcc', which requires a data frame or a matrix with each row consisting of one group, using NA's in groups which have fewer samples.

The following code will create an example dataset, as well as show manual conversion to the desired format.

```
# This is an example of the initial data that I have
# * 10 sample measurements, over 3 groups with 3, 2, and 5 elements respectively
x <- rnorm(10)
x_df <- data.frame( time = c( rep('2001 Q1',3), rep('2001 Q2',2), rep('2001 Q3',5) ), measure = x )
x_df

# This is a manual conversion into the desired format
x_pad <- c( x[1:3], NA, NA, x[4:5], NA, NA, NA, x[6:10] )
x_matrix <- matrix( x_pad, nrow = 3, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c('2001 Q1','2001 Q2','2001 Q3')) )
x_matrix # desired format

# An example of how it will be used
library(qcc)
plot(qcc(x_matrix, type = 'xbar', plot = FALSE))
```

So, I'd like to convert this:

```
      time     measure
1  2001 Q1  0.14680685
2  2001 Q1  0.53593193
3  2001 Q1  0.56097974
4  2001 Q2 -1.48102689
5  2001 Q2  0.18150972
6  2001 Q3  1.72018147
7  2001 Q3 -0.08480855
8  2001 Q3 -2.23208877
9  2001 Q3 -1.15269107
10 2001 Q3  0.57975023
```

... to this ...

```
              [,1]        [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
2001 Q1  0.1468068  0.53593193  0.5609797        NA        NA
2001 Q2 -1.4810269  0.18150972         NA        NA        NA
2001 Q3  1.7201815 -0.08480855 -2.2320888 -1.152691 0.5797502
```

There is probably an easy way (perhaps some usage of reshape or reshape2 casting that I'm not familiar with?), but a bunch of searching hasn't helped me so far.

Thanks for any help!

==========

From one of the solutions below, the following will generate the final qcc xbar plot, including group labels:

```
library(splitstackshape)
out_df <- dcast( getanID( x_df, 'time' ), time~.id, value.var='measure' )
qcc( out_df[,-1], type = 'xbar', labels = out_df[,1] )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a sequence column ('.id') using `getanID` from `splitstackshape` and use `dcast` from `data.table` to convert the long format to wide format.  The output of `splitstackshape` is a data.table.  When we load `splitstackshape`, data.table will also be loaded.  So, if you already have the devel version of data.table, then the `dcast` from `data.table` can be used as well.

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast(getanID(df1, 'time'), time~.id, value.var='measure')
#     time          1           2          3         4         5
#1: 2001 Q1  0.1468068  0.53593193  0.5609797        NA        NA
#2: 2001 Q2 -1.4810269  0.18150972         NA        NA        NA
#3: 2001 Q3  1.7201815 -0.08480855 -2.2320888 -1.152691 0.5797502
```

#### Update

As @snoram mentioned in the comments, function `rowid` from `data.table` makes it easier to use just `data.table` alone

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), time ~ rowid(time), value.var = "measure")
```

Comment: I like this solution in particular, because of how concise it is and because it keeps it as a dataframe. 'qcc' doesn't seem to like data tables very much. Not sure if it's proper StackOverflow etiquette, but I will edit my question to include how to use the above solution in the actuall qcc plotting as well, in case anyone finds this question looking for qcc solutions.

Comment: @JChou If you want to convert the output  to `data.frame`, you can use `setDF(res)` where `res <- dcast(getanID(...`

Comment: Thank you, awesome! I was doing a whole bunch of as.data.frame() conversions on the data tables. To be honest, I just need to learn about data tables! (I'm relatively new to R in general).

Comment: @JChou I think the `setDF/setDT` functions were introduced in v1.9.3 or so.  The devel version have many interesting functions including `dcast` to reshape multiple value columns and `melt` to convert to long with multiple measure columns.

Comment: I believe that in 2018 one would do: `dcast(x_df, time ~ rowid(time), measure.vars = "measure")`, no need for `splitstackshape`.

Comment: Thank you! This saved me from doing it in a very filthy way.

Comment: I posted a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70128868/combine-long-format-data-frames-with-different-length-and-convert-to-wide-format but stumbled upon your answer. So thank you! However, I do wonder how to also group by `id` if it contains many individuals, as is the case in my dataset

Answer (score 7):

You'll need an intermediate variable that gives a "within-time" id.  You can create it and reshape like this

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

group_by(X, time) %>%
  mutate(seq = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(seq, measure)
```

Comment: There is also a `row_number()`  that can be handy as well.

Comment: This saved me! I had no idea I had to use `ungroup()` inbetween `group_by()` and `spread()`. Do you know why that is necessary?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if you _have_ to.  I just have an obsessive habit of ungrouping my data unless I have a reason to keep in grouped in subsequent commands. I get the same results on this sample of data whether I ungroup or not.

Answer (score 5):

Another `splitstackshape` approach

```
cSplit(setDT(df)[, toString(measure), by='time'], 'V1', ',')

#      time       V1_1        V1_2       V1_3      V1_4      V1_5
#1: 2001 Q1  0.1468068  0.53593193  0.5609797        NA        NA
#2: 2001 Q2 -1.4810269  0.18150972         NA        NA        NA
#3: 2001 Q3  1.7201815 -0.08480855 -2.2320888 -1.152691 0.5797502
```

Or using the `devel` version of `data.table` a similar approach after pasting together the 'measure' by the grouping column 'time' would be using `tstrsplit` to split the 'V1' column generated from `toString(measure)`.

```
 setDT(df)[, toString(measure), by ='time'][, c(list(time), tstrsplit(V1, ', '))]
```

Also, we can add `type.convert=TRUE` in `tstrsplit` to convert the `class` of the split columns.  By default it is `FALSE`.

Comment: That is a cute way.  I didn't think about this.

Comment: Thanks @akrun :) I think I got to know this way from one of your old answers

Comment: Using the devel version, you can also use `tstrsplit`.  Something like `setDT(df1)[, toString(measure), by ='time'][, c(list(time), tstrsplit(V1, ', '))]`

Comment: Your solution is more compact though.  I will add that.